# Add element in Spinner in android

Tags: android

I have a question about add item to spinner.
In my class I have:

```
ArrayAdapter<SchType> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SchType>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, schTypesList);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

typeSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Now, I want to add one more item to spinner. This item should always be on bottom of list and this is not object `schType`. So I want to build spinner where I have list of objects from `schTypesList` and bottom of this list is other view which is not object from `schTypesList`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of String objects as that's what will be shown in the Spinner, then you are not restricted by object types.